# Avoid receiving LinkedIn contact request

Tags: linkedin, contacts

I dont want to receive contact request on LinkedIn. Is it possible? Can I remove the "send contact request" button from my profile so no one can send me requests?!

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to remove `connect` tab from profile. But you can control who can send you invitations. From [Help Center](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/70/~/controlling-who-can-send-you-invitations):

> You can [select who can send you invitations](https://www.linkedin.com/settings/?modal=nsettings-invite-receive&tab=email) from the Communications tab of the [Privacy & Settings](https://www.linkedin.com/settings/?&tab=email) page. You'll receive a notification each time a LinkedIn member invites you to connect.
>
> Select one of the following preferences:
>
> 1. Anyone on LinkedIn (Recommended)
> 2. Only people who know your email address or appear in your "Imported Contacts" list
> 3. Only people who appear in your "Imported Contacts" list

In your case you can select the second option.

See this to know more about [Connect/Send InMail](https://help.linkedin.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20623/~/missing-connect-button-on-profile).

Comment: if I choose third option and keep my "imported contacts" empty, then no one can send me contact request ?! is it true?

Comment: Yes, Its true, but I am not sure that you can keep "imported contacts" empty or not. So please check from yourself.